# Multiple Image on rollover

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is have 2 images appear when I rollover an image, the first is achieved by using this code, and is a normal rollover:

```
<a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('','','images/image2.jpg',1)">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="imageDesc" width="120" height="125" id="Ammar" /></a>
```

The second image is an info text box which I went to appear slightly offset from the original (i.e. bottom-right or bottom-left with a slight over lap).

How can this effect be achieved? [Here](http://qabila.tv/exampleRoll.html) is an example for clarification

Comment: Is this a question? if so, what's the question?

Comment: Edited for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your first image in a div and set `id="myDiv` you can change the contents of the div like this in your `onmouseover` code

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML="<img ... /> <img ... />";
```